# Spectrum of discretized Laplace operator with homogeneous Neumann B.C.s

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, laplacian, finite-differences

Consider the Laplace operator over a 1D domain with homogeneous Neumann B.C.s. The cell-centered Finite Volumes discretization of this operator on a uniform grid looks as follows, which is a well-known result:
\begin{equation}
L_n = \frac{1}{h}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & -2 &1\\
&\ddots &\ddots &\ddots\\
& & 1 & -2 & 1\\
& & & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}.
\end{equation}

My question is whether there exists a closed form solution for the eigenvalues of $L_n$. I am aware that closed forms exist for the periodic and homogeneous Dirichlet cases, but I haven't been able to find anything for the homogeneous Neumann case. I also haven't been able to make much progress in terms of a proof, but I have found that given $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$:
\begin{equation}
x^*L_nx = \frac{1}{h}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |x_k - x_{k+1}|^2.
\end{equation}

Does anyone have a suggestion of where to look or how to proceed with a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are well-known, but I am blanking on a textbook reference. Here are some lecture notes with the values https://math.mit.edu/icg/resources/teaching/18.336-spring2013/Notes_Set2.pdf

Comment: Thank you! No idea why this was so hard to find, but the solution is what I should have expected.

Comment: I noticed that the matrix from the lecture notes is slightly different, because it uses a vertex centered, instead of a cell-centered scheme. This yields slightly different eigenvectors, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After some suggested reading and a few attempts, the eigenvectors turned out to be:
\begin{align}
\xi_k = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\left(j+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
\end{bmatrix}_{\forall j\in\{0\dots n-1\}},\quad \forall k\in\{0\dots n-1\},
\end{align}

with corresponding eigenvalues:
\begin{align}
\lambda_k = 
\frac{2}{h}\left(\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi k}{n}\right)-1\right),
\quad\forall k\in\{0\dots n-1\}.
\end{align}